# Java blocking queue containing only unique elements

Tags: java, queue

sort of like a "blocking set". How can I implement a blocking queue where adding a member that is already in the set is ignored?

Answer (score 14):

I wrote this class to solve a similar problem:

```
/**
 * Linked blocking queue with {@link #add(Object)} method, which adds only element, that is not already in the queue.
 */
public class SetBlockingQueue<T> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<T> {

    private Set<T> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

    /**
     * Add only element, that is not already enqueued.
     * The method is synchronized, so that the duplicate elements can't get in during race condition.
     * @param t object to put in
     * @return true, if the queue was changed, false otherwise
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized boolean add(T t) {
        if (set.contains(t)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            set.add(t);
            return super.add(t);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Takes the element from the queue.
     * Note that no synchronization with {@link #add(Object)} is here, as we don't care about the element staying in the set longer needed.
     * @return taken element
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    @Override
    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        T t = super.take();
        set.remove(t);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if we cared about removing the element from the queue and from the set atomically ?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new class that composes a BlockingQueue, a Set, and a lock. When you put() you test against the set while holding a lock that prevents get() from running. When you get() you remove the item from the set so that it can be put() again in the future.

Answer (score 3):

A blocking queue implementation backed by a linked hash set for predictable iteration order and constant time addition, removal and contains operations:

[There you go](https://github.com/abayer/incubator-marmotta/blob/master/platform/marmotta-core/src/main/java/org/apache/marmotta/platform/core/util/LinkedHashSetBlockingQueue.java).

Comment: @horec - Is that feeling coming from looking at the code or from actually trying it? Looking at t he code I had the same concern but have't really give it a shot yet

Comment: Your link is dead :-(

Comment: @rcomblen - fixed.

Comment: @forhas Your link died again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working in this exact same issue. The solution that was proposed has some problems, like not keeping the set and the queue with the same elements.

I'm not 100% sure if it's necessary, but I'm guessing it is. Also, it doesn't contemplate other methods, ie offer and put.

If we use 'BlockingQueue' as the backing queue for keeping things in sync, none of the relevant methods work. The lock of the inner queue conflicts with the  monitor lock and the interactions between blocking methods

At the end I have to implement something like that (full implementation in [UniqueBlockingQueue](https://gist.github.com/tulioballari/d85094e6b951ee2258e3ae67c774b36c) and test in [UniqueBlockingQueueTest](https://gist.github.com/tulioballari/9d8806360147dc0241708cd460eaa615) ) based in the blocking queues already present in the jdk.

```
public class UniqueBlockingQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E> implements BlockingQueue<E> {

  private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
  private final Condition notFull = lock.newCondition();

  private HashSet<E> set = new HashSet<>();
  private LinkedList<E> queue = new LinkedList<>();

  private final int capacity;
  private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

  @Override
  public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(e);

    final var lock = this.lock;
    final var count = this.count;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        while (count.get() == capacity || set.contains(e)) {
            notFull.await();
        }
        queue.add(e);
        set.add(e);

        final var c = count.getAndIncrement();
        if (c + 1 < capacity) {
            notFull.signal();
        }
        if (c == 0) {
            notEmpty.signal();
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public E take() throws InterruptedException {
    final var lock = this.lock;
    final var count = this.count;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        while (count.get() == 0) {
            notEmpty.await();
        }
        var e = queue.poll();
        set.remove(e);

        final var c = count.getAndDecrement();
        if (c > 1) {
            notEmpty.signal();
        }
        if (c == capacity) {
            notFull.signal();
        }
        return e;
   } finally {
       lock.unlock();
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override add and put methods of any implementation of `BlockingQueue<T>` to check first if the element is already within the queue, e.g.

```
@Override
public boolean add(T elem) {
    if (contains(elem))
        return true;
    return super.add(elem);
}
```

Comment: good but not optimal as the normal BlockingQueue implementation of contains() requires a traversal of entire queue

Comment: I would say "optimal" is subjective. Unless you roll your own the other simple option is the one suggested by spike and that is a classic space vs. time tradeoff. So while either could be argued as the best solution depending on the use I give my up vote to this because of its simplicity.

Comment: if "optimal" includes correct, then this implementation would fail as it is a race condition.

Answer (score -3):

```
class BlockingSet extends ArrayBlockingQueue<E> {
   /*Retain all other methods except put*/
   public void put(E o) throws InterruptedException {
      if (!this.contains(o)){
         super.put(o);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The implementation of `contains` iterates over the list, this would be really slow...