# is there something like a BlockingSet

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, set, queue

I am searching for something like a BlockingSet. Currently I am working wir `BlockingQueue`'s but it would be nice if i could guarantee that there are only individual objects in the Collection. `Insert()`, `take()`, `put()`, `remove()` and so on should be in O(logn).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5237283/3255152

Comment: @mfulton26 Worth noting that one of the most upvoted answer there is really wrong... See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3121453/829571