# My try of implementing the BlockingQueue containing only unique elements

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

My problem is very similar to: [Java blocking queue containing only unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237283/java-blocking-queue-containing-only-unique-elements)

But I need just 2 methods: `put` and `take` of `BlockingQueue` Interface. The answers given in that topic are not good in my opinion. First of them works on 2 collections and the second one is too huge and not tested at all.

This is my try:

```
public class ConcurrentBufferSet<T> implements ConcurrentBuffer<T> {

    private Set<T> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void put(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            set.add(t);
            notify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T take () throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (set.isEmpty()) {
                wait();
            }
            Iterator<T> it = set.iterator();
            T t = it.next();
            it.remove();
            notify();
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the test which fails from time to time because of timeout:

```
    @Test(timeout = 300)
    public void testManyThreadsOnSingleBuffer() throws InterruptedException {

        // given:
        AtomicInteger putCount = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger takenCount = new AtomicInteger();
        ConcurrentBuffer<Integer> buffer = new ConcurrentBufferSet<>();

        int[] producerIterations = {54, 93, 1, 44, 20};
        int[] consumerIterations = {90, 99, 10, 2, 11};
        int producerIterationsSum = Arrays.stream(producerIterations).sum();
        int consumerIterationsSum = Arrays.stream(consumerIterations).sum();

        // when:
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for(int i = 0; i < producerIterations.length; i ++) {
            exec.execute(createProducerRunnable(buffer, putCount, producerIterations[i]));
            exec.execute(createConsumerRunnable(buffer, takenCount, consumerIterations[i]));
        }
        exec.shutdown();
        exec.awaitTermination(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        // then:
        assertEquals(producerIterationsSum, consumerIterationsSum);
        assertEquals(putCount.get(), takenCount.get());
        assertEquals(producerIterationsSum, putCount.get());
        assertEquals(consumerIterationsSum, takenCount.get());
        assertEquals(producerIterationsSum - consumerIterationsSum, buffer.size());
    }
```

When I replace my implementation with original LinkedBlockingQueue then the tests always works well. What is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Is `exec` and `ExecutorService` ? If so, use `submit` instead of `execute` as letter might be executed on calling thread.

Comment: didn't help....

Comment: @Antoniossss where did you get that from? The `execute` method of an `ExecutorService` has the same semantic as `submit`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable) "Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, **or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation**."

Comment: @Antoniossss and what’s the difference to `submit`? The particular `ExecutorService` (which is an extension of `Executor`) decides, how it executes the given command, regardless which method you use.

Comment: That part came to me via experience. I haven't use implementation that would execute `submit` on the calling thread but I have used ones that did that nasty trick on `execute`

Comment: @tester01020304 you can try to include all the relatedcode to create reproduceable example, maybe than it will be easier for someone to help you

Comment: @Antoniossss all common executor services implement `submit` by wrapping the runnable or callable in a `FutureTask` or such alike and passing it to `execute`. If you are assuming a weird implementation doing fundamentally different things in `submit` and `execute`, nothing does guaranty that `execute` will be the one using the calling thread and `submit` using new threads. It could perfectly be the other way round. Even more, there is no reason to assume that the OP uses such a strange thing. Especially when we see the standard factory `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);`

Comment: @tester01020304 without the actual code of the producer and consumer threads, it’s impossible to say what happens. What looks strange, are these `producerIterations` and `consumerIterations`. Why do you expect the consumers to have a different result than what the producers produced?

Comment: As far as I remember it was one of imlementations provided by JDK. Its fair to assume that OP is using pure JDK right?I don't remember the exact details, but there is a reason why I remembered that fact - as I had to learn this the hard way. Besides, its just a "may help advice" not "will help" based on my experience. If that is something that have negative impact on whoamever may read this, than I am sorry to hear that.

Comment: @Antoniossss well, that’s how rumors start, leading to developers retelling the story of “I don’t know why, but X is better than Y”. If you can name an actual JDK executor service, where such things happen, name it. Otherwise, I suggest to drop that story into the “things I probably misremember” bin. But yes, `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` suggests the OP is using pure JDK.

Comment: I would find it for you because it is not that I misremember a thing - as it was as I described - but I think that it is just not worth of my time.

Comment: OK I have found the solution. The test is bad. The implementation adds only unique values so there are no enough elements for all consumers. They will be waiting forever.